# Work spaces naming is not working

Tags: gnome, workspaces, workspace-switcher

This one is ground to dust all around, but I still cant get it to work. All I want is to name my work spaces in Ubuntu.
what is the easiest way to get this to work? I'm running 20.04LTS on a T14 Gen1 Thinkpad. My goal is that when i use Ctrl+Alt+Up\Down, instead of meaningless optional screens, I will see a pre-chosen name associated with every work space.
I tried Compizconfig, tweaks, and other random options I found online.
A solution will be hugely appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Your question seem to be meaningful,  but you can add additional grammer support , spaces , commas to organise this question , So I would suggest doing some [edit]s .

Comment: What do you mean with "meaningless optional screens"? The workspace indicator? Probably not possible to add the name there, unless there is an extension for that which I overlooked. There are, however, extensions that display a workspace indicator on the top bar that is displayed on hover over (the official "Workspace Indicator") or directly. A provided answer allows to display the names in the Activities overview.

Comment: I edited, Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Thanks @vanadium, names appearing when I press super key (on the right, work space menu) is really good enough for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Workspace Titles` GNOME Shell Extension works for me  in 20.04.3 LTS

[image]

After installing the extension press <kbd>Left Windows</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd> key to provide the workspace overview and then double click on the title and change it to what you require (as shown in the below graphic). I changed the first one to `screen 1` and the last one (of 3) to `xxx` but left the second workspace as the default title to provide an example. You can rename them at will by double clicking on the title when in the Workspace overview.

[image]

Comment: Good suggestion, but not what the OP specifically asks (i.e. displaying the workspace name during a change of workspace using the shortcut keys)

Comment: I can not thank you enough. This is exactly what I meant to achieve, and once I managed to install it it seem to work perfectly. Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Perhaps you can can accept the answer (the grey tick by the side of it) and upvote so that others can find the solution easily in the future.

Comment: Can't up-vote since I'm new, accepted. Thanks!

Comment: your rep just went up so you probably can upvote now... thanks for accepting!